# How to resize the IPhone video to a specific dimension, and add some more features

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, video, uiview, resize

Did anyone tried to resize an video, for adding more views around it?

Can anyone give me any hint/recommendation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seams that people knowing it, don't tell :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you can't resize the video: it is only full screen.

[iPhone Dev Center: Multimedia Support](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html)

Comment: I even saw somewhere a hint, but i forgot it.